# Generating all permutations by the minimum transposition number C -> C #

Tags: c#, c, permutation

I would like to convert this code into C # but something is wrong. I did not want to do that with pointers. Can anyone know how to improve it soon? This is Generating all permutations by the minimum number of transpositions. This is the code I wanted to convert.
[a link](https://github.com/tszymanek/alg_7/blob/master/alg_7_nierek.c).

```
namespace Algorytm8
{
    class Program
    {
        private int[] P;
        private int count, n;
        public int silnia(int n) {    
            return (n == 1 || n == 0) ? 1: silnia(n-1) * n;    
        }
        public void swap(int i, int j)
        {
            int pom;
            pom = P[i];
            P[i] = P[j];
            P[j] = pom;
        }
        public int b(int m, int i)
        {
            if ((m % 2 == 0) && (m > 2))
            {
                if (i < m - 1)
                {
                    return i;
                }
                else
                {
                    return m - 2;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return m - 1;
            }
        }    
        public void perm(int m)
        {
            int Mi;
            int[] I = P;    
            for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
            {
                I[i] = 1;
            }
            Mi = 1;
            while (count < silnia(m))
            {
                if (I[Mi]==Mi)
                {
                    if (I[Mi]==1 && Mi==1)
                    {
                        count++;
                        Console.Write(count);
                        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(P[i]);
                        }
                        Console.Write("\n");
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i <= Mi; i++)
                    {
                        I[i] = 1;
                    }
                    Mi++;      
                }
                if (I[Mi] < Mi)
                {    
                    int i = I[Mi];
                    swap(b(Mi, i), Mi);
                    I[Mi]++;
                    Mi = 1;                        
                }    
            }            
        }
        public void getData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Podaj ilość elementów: ");
            int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            P = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                P[i] = i + 1;
            }
            perm(n - 1);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.getData();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: bad values ​​enumerate me

Comment: Then take a debugger and debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy/pasted the C program it converts rather easily to C#

Some main issues you had: `int[] I = P;` doesn't make a new array. Change `int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` to `n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`. The compiler should have given you warning about initialization.

Change the `swap` to `swap(ref int i, ref int j)`, this is more like the C version and is more generalized.

```
class Program
{
    private int[] P;
    private int count, n;

    public int silnia(int n)
    {
        return (n == 1 || n == 0) ? 1 : silnia(n - 1) * n;
    }

    public void swap(ref int i, ref int j)
    {
        int temp = i;
        i = j;
        j = temp;
    }

    public int B(int m, int i)
    {
        if ((m % 2 == 0) && (m > 2))
        {
            if (i < (m - 1))
                return i;
            else
                return m - 2;
        }
        else
            return m - 1;
    }

    public void PERM(int m)
    {
        int[] I = new int[m + 1];

        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
            I[i] = 1;
        int Mi = 1;

        while (count < silnia(m))
        {
            if (I[Mi] == Mi)
            {
                if (I[Mi] == 1 && Mi == 1)
                {
                    count++;
                    Console.Write("{0}:\t", count);
                    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                        Console.Write("{0} ", P[i]);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                for (int i = 1; i <= Mi; i++)
                    I[i] = 1;
                Mi++;
            }
            if (I[Mi] < Mi)
            {
                int i = I[Mi];
                swap(ref P[B(Mi, i)], ref P[Mi]);
                I[Mi]++;
                Mi = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public void getData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Podaj ilość elementów: ");
        n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        P = new int[n + 1]; 
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            P[i] = i;
        count = 0;
        PERM(n);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program prog = new Program();
        prog.getData();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```